# how to pass string to view in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I display the output in html? Here is my sample code in ruby:

```
  m = ["a","b", "c"]
  m.each do |i|
  @html = "<p>"+#{i}+"</p>"  
  end
```

I have a separate view file which reads the @html string:

```
  <%= @html.html_safe</p>
```

My question is, how do i invoke the view file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fix typo in your code

```
@html = "<p>"+#{i}+"</p>"
```

should read

```
@html = "<p>#{i}</p>"
```

Now coming to the point just pass this at the end of your action

```
erb :<name-of-your-template>
```

this assumes you are having your erb templates under views directory